Ophthalmology game: stones fading in, and fading out
A car has a beam.
It sees various stones along the way, that it has to avoid.
The stones are different colors.
Tapping on a stone makes the stones that color go into contrast with the rest of the road (so you can see it and similarly color-category or color-umbrella stones), while, the others, fade, in (they become the same color as the road and you cannot see them any more).
If the car gets too close to a stone a faded in, unshowing, color, it stops.
The car can memorize a set number of colors, which, it can memorize, and, when the user clicks on the car memory cloud, on  one of the stones, the contrast, makes, the stones, that color, show contrasted (they show more), while the others colors fade (they, show less
When a stone fades, it becomes the same color and you can't see it. But when the car gets close to it it stops.
If you keep more stones the same color into memory you can make them fade in rather than out, quicker, (when you click drag or swipe on one of these stones in the memory cloud).
Clicking on a stone (one at a time, in, an exclusive, manner) makes it more visible. (the others fade out (,into the road). You can try to click on more then one stone in the memory cloud to get a tried smoothing effect, but the stones in the memory cloud pull to one single stone, the car slows, and goes, into, an, automatic, hazardous (mode
The car has to make, it  safe  to the end.
This could be a game that currently Android does not cater to.
Where can I find such an app?
If more than one app of this sort (for instance, others, where other objects, even on the road, (of, different  con si s tency or on walls) could exist, then, more than one eye condition (including, those, induced by medication (real, imagined, or comprehended), could be comprehended.
Is there anything like that available on the play store?
Where can I download it.
I like to share my idea for you to implement it (for, example, in a game).
Thanks.
